# Creating a "push_back" Function for Array

Tags: c++, arrays

My assignment is to create push_back and pop_back functions for a SimpleVector which have to do basically what you imagine they have to do. I'm trying to add an element to an existing array in this fashion but it isn't working. It adds 0 instead of the number I pass in in main. Any ideas as to why?

> **SimpleVector.h**

```
// SimpleVector class template
#ifndef SIMPLEVECTOR_H
#define SIMPLEVECTOR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <new>       // Needed for bad_alloc exception
#include <cstdlib>   // Needed for the exit function

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class SimpleVector
{
private:
    T *aptr;          // To point to the allocated array
    int arraySize;    // Number of elements in the array
    void memError();  // Handles memory allocation errors
    void subError();  // Handles subscripts out of range

public:
    // Default constructor
    SimpleVector()
    {
        aptr = 0;
        arraySize = 0;
    }

    // Constructor declaration
    SimpleVector(int);

    // Copy constructor declaration
    SimpleVector(const SimpleVector &);

    // Destructor declaration
    ~SimpleVector();

    // Accessor to return the array size
    int size() const
    {
        return arraySize;
    }

    // Accessor to return a specific element
    T getElementAt(int position);

    // Overloaded [] operator declaration
    T &operator[](const int &);

    void push_back(SimpleVector, int);

    void pop_back(SimpleVector, int);
};

//***********************************************************
// Constructor for SimpleVector class. Sets the size of the *
// array and allocates memory for it.                       *
//***********************************************************

template<class T>
SimpleVector<T>::SimpleVector(int s)
{
    arraySize = s;
    // Allocate memory for the array.
    try
    {
        aptr = new T[s];
    }
    catch (bad_alloc)
    {
        memError();
    }

    // Initialize the array.
    for (int count = 0; count < arraySize; count++)
        *(aptr + count) = 0;
}

//*******************************************
// Copy Constructor for SimpleVector class. *
//*******************************************

template<class T>
SimpleVector<T>::SimpleVector(const SimpleVector &obj)
{
    // Copy the array size.
    arraySize = obj.arraySize;

    // Allocate memory for the array.
    aptr = new T[arraySize];
    if (aptr == 0)
        memError();

    // Copy the elements of obj's array.
    for (int count = 0; count < arraySize; count++)
        *(aptr + count) = *(obj.aptr + count);
}

//**************************************
// Destructor for SimpleVector class.  *
//**************************************

template<class T>
SimpleVector<T>::~SimpleVector()
{
    if (arraySize > 0)
        delete[] aptr;
}

//*******************************************************
// memError function. Displays an error message and     *
// terminates the program when memory allocation fails. *
//*******************************************************

template<class T>
void SimpleVector<T>::memError()
{
    cout << "ERROR:Cannot allocate memory.\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//***********************************************************
// subError function. Displays an error message and         *
// terminates the program when a subscript is out of range. *
//***********************************************************

template<class T>
void SimpleVector<T>::subError()
{
    cout << "ERROR: Subscript out of range.\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//*******************************************************
// getElementAt function. The argument is a subscript.  *
// This function returns the value stored at the sub-   *
// script in the array.                                  *
//*******************************************************

template<class T>
T SimpleVector<T>::getElementAt(int sub)
{
    if (sub < 0 || sub >= arraySize)
        subError();
    return aptr[sub];
}

//*******************************************************
// Overloaded [] operator. The argument is a subscript. *
// This function returns a reference to the element     *
// in the array indexed by the subscript.               *
//*******************************************************

template<class T>
T &SimpleVector<T>::operator[](const int &sub)
{
    if (sub < 0 || sub >= arraySize)
        subError();
    return aptr[sub];
}
#endif

template<class T>
void SimpleVector<T>::push_back(SimpleVector obj, int newval)
{
    arraySize = obj.arraySize + 1;

    // Allocate memory for the array.
    aptr = new T[arraySize];
    if (aptr == 0)
        memError();

    // Copy the elements of obj's array.
    for (int count = 0; count < (arraySize - 1); count++)
        *(aptr + count) = *(obj.aptr + count);

    obj.aptr[(arraySize)] = newval;

}
```

> **main.cpp**

```
// This program demonstrates the SimpleVector template.
#include <iostream>
#include "SimpleVector.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 10; // Number of elements
    int amtToPrnt = 10;
    int count; // Loop counter

// Create a SimpleVector of ints.
    SimpleVector<int> intTable(SIZE);

// Store values in the two SimpleVectors.
    for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++)
    {
        intTable[count] = (count * 2);
    }

// Display the values in the SimpleVectors.
    cout << "These values are in intTable:\n";
    for (count = 0; count < amtToPrnt; count++)
        cout << intTable[count] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    intTable.push_back(intTable, 20);
    cout << "These values are in intTable after adding one more value:\n";
    for (count = 0; count < ++amtToPrnt; count++)
        cout << intTable[count] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    /*
     intTable.push_back(intTable, 22);
     cout << "These values are in intTable after adding one more value:\n";
     for (count = 0; count < ++amtToPrnt; count++)
     cout << intTable[count] << " ";
     cout << endl;

     intTable.push_back(intTable, 24);
     cout << "These values are in intTable after adding one more value:\n";
     for (count = 0; count < ++amtToPrnt; count++)
     cout << intTable[count] << " ";
     cout << endl;
     */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Off Topic: in your header the include guard is closed off too early.

Answer (score 2):

> SimpleVector.h

```
void push_back(int);
```

I remove `SimpleVector` to reduce memory usage.

```
template <class T>
void SimpleVector<T>::push_back(int newval){
   // Allocate memory for the array in the temporary array.
   T * tmpArray = new T [arraySize + 1]; 

   // Copy the elements of old array.
   for(int count = 0; count < arraySize; count++)
      *(tmpArray + count) = *(aptr + count);

   // Push new value
   *(tmpArray + arraySize) = newval;

   // Delete old array
   delete[] aptr;

   // Copy array
   aptr = tmpArray;

   // Increase size
   arraySize++;
}
```

> main.cpp

```
intTable.push_back(20);
amtToPrnt++;

cout << "These values are in intTable after adding one more value:\n";
for (count = 0; count < amtToPrnt; count++)
    cout << intTable[count] << " ";
cout << endl;
```

Result :

[image]

Side note:
You should refactor your `SimpleVector`. Don't use pass by value if you didn't need it. And I suggest to made the `arraySize` public to know how many data are in your `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleVector<T>::push_back`is a bit of a wreck. Let's take a look, shall we?

```
void SimpleVector<T>::push_back(SimpleVector obj, int newval)
```

`SimpleVector obj` is passed by value, so the `obj` operated on is a copy. Recommend passing by reference. But why do this in the first place? What use is a push_back that pushes back a `SimpleVector` AND a new value? Recommend rethinking this approach.

```
{
    arraySize = obj.arraySize + 1;

    // Allocate memory for the array.
    aptr = new T[arraySize];
```

OK. That's all good. Except, what if `aptr` already pointed at memory? You'd have to `delete[]` that first, but then what would you copy? Recommend working with a temporary variable here and assigning the temporary after the copying and deleting is finished.

```
    if (aptr == 0)
        memError();
```

This will never happen. `new` throws `bad_alloc` on allocation errors so the program will never get here if `new` failed. Earlier the program did this:

```
try
{
    aptr = new T[s];
}
catch (bad_alloc)
{
    memError();
}
```

It's very likely you want to do it again.

It is also bad form to use 0 in place of `nullptr`. 0 is a magic number AND it's not a pointer.

```
    // Copy the elements of obj's array.
    for (int count = 0; count < (arraySize - 1); count++)
        *(aptr + count) = *(obj.aptr + count);
```

All groovy. Nothing to see here other than clunky-looking pointer arithmetic where `aptr[count]` would have sufficed. However as outlined above, this is unexpected behaviour for a `push_back` function.

```
obj.aptr[(arraySize)] = newval;
```

`obj` is still `obj.arraySize` sized and `arraySize` is one bigger. Next, the array is indexed 0..`obj.arraySize-1`, so this writes not one, but two elements past the end of the array and invokes undefined behaviour. Who knows what will result from doing this? I sure don't.

Next, it modifies `obj` which is a copy that is about to be destroyed. I suspect `*(aptr + arraySize - 1) = newval;` would be more useful.

```
}
```

While I was writing this a perfectly serviceable what to do answer went up. Refer to it.

Optimization: Instead of always increasing by 1, why not save yourself a lot of resizing and copying and increase the size by a factor of two?

Answer (score 0):

When you call push_back, the first parameter is passed by value. In other words, a temporary copy is created. Then you allocate a new array (without deleting the original - memory leak!) and change the ptr in `this` to the new array. Fine, but then you put the new value into the temporary vector, which is destroyed after returning from the function.